# Why doesn't my domain resolve to the hostname CNAME/ALIAS I've specified?

Tags: dns, cname

I have a domain set with a `CNAME` alias to point to Heroku, but it is not resolving.

Here is a link to a screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/03226ntoc4

And here is the output from `nslookup`:

```
$ nslookup -query=any tyger.ac. dns1.name-services.com
Server:  dns1.name-services.com
Address:  98.124.192.1

tyger.ac        nameserver = dns3.name-services.com
tyger.ac
        primary name server = dns1.name-services.com
        responsible mail addr = info.name-services.com
        serial  = 2002050701
        refresh = 10800 (3 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
tyger.ac        nameserver = dns2.name-services.com
tyger.ac        MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = eforwardct.name-services.com
tyger.ac        MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = eforwardct3.name-services.com
tyger.ac        MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = eforwardct2.name-services.com
tyger.ac        nameserver = dns4.name-services.com
tyger.ac        nameserver = dns5.name-services.com
tyger.ac        nameserver = dns1.name-services.com
dns2.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.197.1
dns3.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.193.1
dns1.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.192.1
dns4.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.194.1
dns5.name-services.com  internet address = 98.124.196.1
```

Here is the destination host:

```
$ nslookup mie-6031.herokussl.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    elb033514-473924049.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Addresses:  50.16.211.233
          23.23.138.171
          54.243.232.221
Aliases:  mie-6031.herokussl.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `CNAME` alias then you must not have other DNS records (e.g., `NS`) for that name - see [rfc1912 - section 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912).

I guess that eNom interface just filters out this "CNAME for the whole domain". You must point your root domain name to IP addresses (or make the operator of `.ac` add a `CNAME` in their records - probably impossible).

If you use Amazon services, then [this information about Amazon Route53 and its alias extension](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html) might also be interesting for you (see number 3).

Comment: Heroku doesn't support A name records. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#dns-and-domain-configuration. They only support using CNAME aliases, and ENom appears to support CNAME for root domains. I am guessing they emulate it or something. When I had CNAME pointed to the non-SSL Heroku server, it was working fine.

Comment: Here is more about Heroku and root domains. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain. "Zone apex domains (aka “naked”, “bare” or “root” domains), e.g., example.com, using conventional DNS A-records are not supported on Heroku." And more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains.

Comment: If DNS provider allow aliasing of root domain then they usually use special record name for this (alias as Route53 or something like this as heroku say here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#cname-functionality-at-the-apex ). If ENom support just CNAME and you have other domains with same configuration that just works then maybe they emulate this by scripting and not serve multiple IP for heroku? Can you give me a domain name on ENom with CNAME for root and rest of record similar to this one?

Comment: Ok I turned off mail forwarding (I needed it to get my SSL) and set and reset the A and CNAME records and now it is working!